# Google Maps Embed Api - Invalid parameter q

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I creating a WebApp in NodeJs, Express and Pug/Jade.

The following pug code works

```
iframe#map(width="100%", height="600", frameborder="0", style="border:0"
    src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?' +
        'key=MY_API_KEY&q=56.8860513,-9.5357577')
```

However the following code does not work

```
src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?' +
        'key=MY_API_KEY&q=#{data.long},#{data.lat}')
```

The error I get is `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'q' parameter.` - Any suggestions/ideas?

Note data is a valid json file. That I can print out in the pug document using `h2 Location of #{data.fname}`.
The variable is created by `app.locals.data = myData;`

Comment: What do you get when you output `data`? Does it have valid fields `data.lang` and `data.lat`?

Comment: data = `{ fname: 'Daniel', lat: 8.5357577, long: 51.8860513 }`

Comment: How is this rendered in your output html - `src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?' +
        'key=MY_API_KEY&q=#{data.long},#{data.lat}')`? Are values of `data.long` and `data.lat` inserted correctly if you check in your browser's source code?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEY&q=#{patientData.long},#{patientData.lat}`

Comment: Can you try `src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEY&q=' + data.long + ',' + data.lat + '")`?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Ah, I kept on trying that but using the pug syntax of `#{data.lat}` instead of just `data.lat` I forgot that it is essentially Javascript logic within the quotes. Fully working now, thanks very much! :) - Silly mistake on my behalf

Comment: I have posted that as an answer below with an explanation for the interpolation syntax you have used. Please mark this as accepted if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Done. Thanks again. I also appreciate you letting me know about the new Pug syntax too!

Comment: Thanks @Dean. I have updated my answer and added a note regarding the syntax change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `#{var}` syntax as it has been removed in Pug 2, as [mentioned here](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#removed-language-features)

[*NOTE* This syntax `#{var}` has been removed in Attribute Interpolation i.e. you cannot use this syntax in attribute values, but for contents of elements, you can still use this syntax. e.g. `p my name is #{name}.` ]

Instead define your `src` attribute like this:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_K‌​EY&q=' + data.long + ',' + data.lat + '")
```